Most optimal way to decompose a number as a sum of repdigits
A repdigit is a positive integer consisting of only one digit, e.g. numbers $1$-$9, 11, 2222, 333$. Now, I wanted to know what is the optimal way (that is the least amount of repdigits used) to decompose a number into a sum of repdigits.
Here is an example:
Let n be the number that we want to decompose, say $n = 154$. We cannot be greedy and always choose the repdigit that does not exceed $n$, this gives us $111+33+9+1$. The optimal approach is $88+66$ or $77+77$ or $99+55$, etc.
I wanted to know if there are properties or direct solutions that I can use to solve such a problem without trying to bruteforce all possible combinations that lead to the sum.
